# Image Hierarchy

Tags: html, css, image, zurb-foundation

Currently learning html by way of coding cool sites I find online.  I'm having some trouble figuring out how this site http://sociali.st uses one image for the iPhone case and another image for the iPhone screen (think clipping masks in photoshop). Can't seem to get my head around it?

Here's my code

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="small-6 columns">
        <h1 class="value-prop">Organize the <br>things you love.</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="small-6 columns">
        <div class="phone">
          <img src="http://sociali.st/wp-content/themes/socialist/library
                         /images/views/home/home-introduction-screen.png">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.phone {        
    width: 359px;
    height: 935px;
    background-image: url('http://sociali.st/wp-content/themes/socialist/
                           library/images/components/devices/device-iphone
                           -5c-perspective-left-shell@2x.png?cache=290611593');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic is done using absolute positioning and transparent backgrounds, more like photoshop layers.

Check this:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGxhy

- Use `position: relative` in the `.phone` so we can position its child elements based on its own top/left.
- The #phone-content is already above the phone chrome due to the standard stacking order.
- Then using the `position`, `top` and `left` properties we can move the content layer to match the desired placeholder

Raed some articles (example http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/) related to the css position attributes and it will be very clear to you ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, the easiest is probably using absolute positioning:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="small-6 columns">
        <h1 class="value-prop">Organize the <br>things you love.</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="small-6 columns">
        <div class="phone">
          <img src="http://sociali.st/wp-content/themes/socialist/library/images/views/home/home-introduction-screen.png">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And css:

```
.phone {
    position:relative;
    width: 359px;
    height: 935px;
    background-image: url('http://sociali.st/wp-content/themes/socialist/library/images/components/devices/device-iphone-5c-perspective-left-shell@2x.png?cache=290611593');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.phone img{
    top:130px;
    position:absolute;
    width:285px;
    left:25px;
}
```

I added `position:relative;` to .phone because we are using the `position:absolute;` method.
Then, I just placed it to look like the screen.

Comment: Thanks so much!  Worked like a charm.